# Rotating in edit mode does not rotate at centerpoint

Tags: edit-mode, transforms

[image]

As seen in this gif, rotating by pressing R is not rotating at the centerpoint of the selection. It puts everything weirdly off grid which is messing me up big time. This has never happened before. I know I can fix it by pressing Shift S and aligning it to the grid, but I shouldn't have to do that when I never had to prior. Can anyone help?

Comment: You cut the screen exactly where the most usefull information is - Header. Try to change the Transformation Orientation to Global and set Transform Pivot Point to Active Element.

Comment: ... or switch the pivot point from 'Median' to 'Bounding Box Center' if your object axes are aligned to the element

Comment: Yep, Bounding Box Center fixed it. Thanks to both of you for helping out!